# Binding between a template-generated object and its parent's property

Tags: wpf, vb.net, templates, binding, resources

The title of this question might be wrong, I am not sure how to phrase it. I am trying to implement a very simple dashboard in which users can drag controls around inside a `Canvas` control. I wrote a `MoveThumb` class that inherits `Thumb` to achieve this. It is working well enough. Now, I want to make sure that the user cannot move the draggable control outside the `Canvas`. It is simple enough to write the logic itself to limit the drag boundaries inside this `MoveThumb` class:

```
Public Class MoveThumb
    Inherits Thumb

    Public Sub New()
        AddHandler DragDelta, New DragDeltaEventHandler(AddressOf Me.MoveThumb_DragDelta)
    End Sub

    Private Sub MoveThumb_DragDelta(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As DragDeltaEventArgs)
        Dim item As Control = TryCast(Me.DataContext, Control)

        If item IsNot Nothing Then
            Dim left As Double = Canvas.GetLeft(item)
            Dim top As Double = Canvas.GetTop(item)
            Dim right As Double = left + item.ActualWidth
            Dim bottom As Double = top + item.ActualHeight

            Dim canvasWidth = 450
            Dim canvasHeight = 800

            If left + e.HorizontalChange > 0 Then
                If top + e.VerticalChange > 0 Then
                    If right + e.HorizontalChange < canvasWidth Then
                        If bottom + e.VerticalChange > canvasHeight Then
                            Canvas.SetLeft(item, left + e.HorizontalChange)
                            Canvas.SetTop(item, top + e.VerticalChange)
                        End If
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    End Sub
End Class
```

And the XML:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:diagramDesigner"
        xmlns:s="clr-namespace:diagramDesigner"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas1">
            <Canvas.Resources>
                <ControlTemplate x:Key="MoveThumbTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type s:MoveThumb}">
                    <Rectangle Fill="Transparent"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
                
                <ControlTemplate x:Key="DesignerItemTemplate" TargetType="ContentControl">
                    <Grid DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}">
                        <s:MoveThumb Template="{StaticResource MoveThumbTemplate}" Cursor="SizeAll"/>
                        <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding ContentControl.Content}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>

            </Canvas.Resources>
            
            <ContentControl Name="DesignerItem"
                   Width="100"
                   Height="100"
                   Canvas.Top="100"
                   Canvas.Left="100"
                   Template="{StaticResource DesignerItemTemplate}">
                <Ellipse Fill="Blue" IsHitTestVisible="False"/>
            </ContentControl>
        </Canvas>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Problem is, I am explicitly stating the width and height of the canvas inside that `MoveThumb` class, which means that if my window changes size, and the Canvas changes size, the drag boundaries will remain the same. Ideally, I want to bind `canvasWidth` and `canvasHeight` to the `actualWidth` and `actualHeight` of the Canvas.

I am not sure what is the best way to achieve it. Acquiring the `actualWidth` and `actualHeight` values inside the `MoveThumb_DragDelta` function with something like `actualWidth = mainWindow.Canvas1.ActualWidth` would be quick and simple, but very bad coding practice.

Ideally, I imagine it would be best to pass the limits as arguments to the constructor of `MoveThumb` and stored as global field/property, but I don't see a way to do it, since this class is used as a template in the XML code, and not generated from code-behind. I am not exactly sure if that would work at all, because the `MoveThumb` might be instantized only once (during the creation of the control), so it won't work when the `Canvas` changes it's size afterwards.

So I probably should do some kind of one-way binding between the `actualWidth` of `Canvas1` and `canvasWidth` (declared as global property) of `MoveThumb`. But again, I have no idea how to access it, since `MoveThumb` is used as a `TargetType` of `ControlTemplate` inside `Canvas.Resources`.

I am still pretty new to WPF, and it feels like there should be some very simple way to achieve this, but I'm not seeing it. Can anyone help?

Comment: You can declare a DependecyProperty in MoveThumb that will receive the size, and then set the binding it needs in XAML.
If you understand C#, I can give you an example.

Comment: @EldHasp I understand C# about as much as VB.NET. Sure, an example would be great, because I have not yet learned about DependecyProperties.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example using Dependency Properties:

```cs
public partial class MoveThumb : Thumb
{
    private double privateCanvasWidth = double.NaN, privateCanvasHeight = double.NaN;
    private static readonly Binding bindingActualWidth = new Binding()
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath(ActualWidthProperty),
        RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(Canvas), 1)
    };
    private static readonly Binding bindingActualHeight = new Binding()
    {
        Path = new PropertyPath(ActualHeightProperty),
        RelativeSource = new RelativeSource(RelativeSourceMode.FindAncestor, typeof(Canvas), 1)
    };

    public MoveThumb()
    {
        DragDelta += MoveThumb_DragDelta;
        SetBinding(CanvasWidthProperty, bindingActualWidth);
        SetBinding(CanvasHeightProperty, bindingActualHeight);
    }

    static MoveThumb()
    {
        DefaultStyleKeyProperty.OverrideMetadata(typeof(MoveThumb), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(typeof(MoveThumb)));
    }
    private static void MoveThumb_DragDelta(object sender, DragDeltaEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveThumb thumb = (MoveThumb)sender;
        //FrameworkElement item = thumb.MovableContent;
        //if (item == null)
        //{
        //    return;
        //}

        double left = Canvas.GetLeft(thumb);
        double top = Canvas.GetTop(thumb);
        double right = left + thumb.ActualWidth;
        double bottom = top + thumb.ActualHeight;

        double canvasWidth = thumb.privateCanvasWidth;
        if (double.IsNaN(canvasWidth))
            canvasWidth = 450;
        double canvasHeight = thumb.privateCanvasHeight;
        if (double.IsNaN(canvasHeight))
            canvasWidth = 800;

        left += e.HorizontalChange;
        top += e.VerticalChange;
        right += e.HorizontalChange;
        bottom += e.VerticalChange;

        if (left > 0 &&
            top > 0 &&
            right < canvasWidth &&
            bottom < canvasHeight)
        {
            Canvas.SetLeft(thumb, left);
            Canvas.SetTop(thumb, top);
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
// DependecyProperties
[ContentProperty(nameof(MovableContent))]
public partial class MoveThumb
{

    /// <summary>Canvas Width.</summary>
    public double CanvasWidth
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(CanvasWidthProperty);
        set => SetValue(CanvasWidthProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="CanvasWidth"/>.</summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanvasWidthProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CanvasWidth), typeof(double), typeof(MoveThumb), new PropertyMetadata(double.NaN, CanvasSizeChanged));


    /// <summary>Canvas Height.</summary>
    public double CanvasHeight
    {
        get => (double)GetValue(CanvasHeightProperty);
        set => SetValue(CanvasHeightProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="CanvasHeight"/>.</summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty CanvasHeightProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(CanvasHeight), typeof(double), typeof(MoveThumb), new PropertyMetadata(double.NaN, CanvasSizeChanged));

    // Property change handler.
    // The code is shown as an example.
    private static void CanvasSizeChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        MoveThumb thumb = (MoveThumb)d;

        if (e.Property == CanvasWidthProperty)
        {
            thumb.privateCanvasWidth = (double)e.NewValue;
        }
        else if (e.Property == CanvasHeightProperty)
        {
            thumb.privateCanvasHeight = (double)e.NewValue;
        }
        else
        {
            throw new Exception("God knows what happened!");
        }

        MoveThumb_DragDelta(thumb, new DragDeltaEventArgs(0, 0));
    }


    /// <summary>Movable content.</summary>
    public FrameworkElement MovableContent
    {
        get => (FrameworkElement)GetValue(MovableContentProperty);
        set => SetValue(MovableContentProperty, value);
    }

    /// <summary><see cref="DependencyProperty"/> for property <see cref="MovableContent"/>.</summary>
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MovableContentProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(MovableContent), typeof(FrameworkElement), typeof(MoveThumb), new PropertyMetadata(null));


}
```

In the Project add the theme "Themes\Generic.xaml":

```xml
<ResourceDictionary
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:customcontrols="clr-namespace:EmbedContent.CustomControls"
    xmlns:s="clr-namespace:Febr20y">

    <Style TargetType="{x:Type s:MoveThumb}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type s:MoveThumb}">
                    <ContentPresenter Content="{TemplateBinding MovableContent}"/>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

```xml
    <Grid>
        <Canvas x:Name="Canvas1">
            <s:MoveThumb x:Name="DesignerItem"
                   Width="100"
                   Height="100"
                   Canvas.Top="100"
                   Canvas.Left="100">
                <Ellipse Fill="Blue"/>
            </s:MoveThumb>
      </Canvas>
    </Grid>
```

[Video YouTube](https://youtu.be/sdgzz4-KtYw)
[Source Code](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1vq7q4lkgdiyfNEhNJoa47VE6sWfNMHC9/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: That is incredibly complicated for such a simple requirement. Is there really no simpler way to achieve what I described?

Comment: I tried it out anyway, but it doesn't seem to work. The control is not movable anymore. Moreover, if I create multiple controls from that template, I get an error ": ''CanvasWidth' property was already registered by 'MoveThumb'.'". This is just way too complicated for a simple property binding...

Comment: Perhaps I have incorrectly transferred the logic of the MoveThumb_DragDelta method.
Put a breakpoint in it and check.

Comment: To be completely honest with you, I do understand this code well enough to know what is going on. But it does seem to be way too complicated to begin with. I might be wrong, but that is a whole lot of code for a simple 2 variable binding... Are you absolutely sure this is the right way to go?

Comment: If you need some external properties to which you can set bindings, then you cannot do without dependency properties.
Also, you should not use the DataContext property other than for Data bindings. Through it, the default Context is set and therefore it affects the work of the bindings.
Better use the fallback Tag property.

Comment: I see, thank you for that explanation. Do you have any idea how to make that code you wrote work? I am still trying to figure it out, but I don't really get it yet.

Comment: I found an error in the method - the "more-less" operators are mixed up.
I fixed the code - now it moves normally.
I also added default bindings to make it easier to use in XAML.

Comment: I have improved the implementation.
Added a default template.
Usage in XAML has been greatly simplified.
Check out the changes in my answer.

Comment: I see! And this latest implementation is far easier to understand. Really neat solution. You have my sincere thanks.

Comment: I thought I understood it, but actually that code does not seem to run - I get loads of errors with it, not even sure where to start. Are you sure it is working on your end?

Comment: I have added links to the demo video and the project archive with source codes.
Take a look at the end of my answer.

Comment: Okay, I set it up wrong. Much more clear now. Many thanks. But is it supposed to stick to walls, and also allow to go out of window bounds if you resize the window past the current position of the thumb? Would there be separate logic required to handle that?

Comment: I just copied your method and fixed the error with the wrong comparison operator there.
You can implement any logic you like.
In the MoveThumb_DragDelta method, I showed how to get all the offsets and dimensions of the canvas.
You can process them in any way you want.

Comment: All right, just wanted to check with you if that behavior was intentional. I will get on it. Thank you very much for taking the time to help me with this. Greatly appreciated.